# Get help from programmers

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Sorry if this isn't the right place for this question. I don't know where to turn.
Stackoverflow is great, I have learned a lot! I even have a shortcut for googleing "site:stackoverflow.com" :)

The only problem is that I sometimes would need quicker help.

I spend to many hours on Google, trying to find the "HOW TO" I need for my projects. I am very stubborn and can sit for days trying to find the information, away prioritize all other things.

I know there are schools and books that probably would save me some time, but that just isn't my cup if tea (not an option). I want to learn by doing.

I know there are websites where you can hire a programmer for a projekt. But the thing is I want to build the code myself, controling and understanding every part myself. Also the question I have are often to small for hireing a programmer.

**What I would need is to have access to a expert/experts in different fields, eg. PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, htaccsess (above all PHP). Maybe a mentor is a good word for it.**

I have no problem sharing the questions and answers. For example I would have know problem asking my questions on stackoverflow. Actually it would somethimes be good if there could be more opinions and comments then they guy I hire.

I am willing to pay a monthly fee of 100 USD or something like that.

I want to be able to communicate using mail, Skype and stackoverflow.com.

The person/persons don't have to be available every day.

The person/persons don't have to write and explain everything for me. Since they know the answer they might be able to Google it better than me and find a website that explains it quick and easy. The goal is only to have me learn and understand.

**Any tips on where I can turn?**

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't the type of question Stack Overflow is suited for. You will need to ask on other websites if you want to make a business arrangement.

Comment: I can't help, but let me know if you find something :D

Comment: Once you get 20 reputation, you can go to [Stack Overflow Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: You're looking for a tutor. $100 USD will get you maybe a couple of hours from a qualified professional; if you're really lucky, a university student might tutor you for minimum wage or close to it, but you have no guarantee that he knows what he's talking about.

Comment: First this isn't the right place to be asking this, stackoverflow is **only** for programming related questions.  And second, why not just ask each question here?  This is what the site was made for, plus you don't need to spend the extra cash.

Comment: I understand darvids0n, sorry. This was not menth to be a business arrangement. I need guidense on where I could start looking for such a mentor/service. Maybe you can give me some tips on these "other sites".

Comment: $100 USD a month?! Depending on country and region that is not even an hour of work.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. Udo Held, the help I need is probebly less than an hour of work per month, but I see your point. 1200 USD per year would require the company to have over hundreds of customers like me :) Would it be OK if I contacted people on Stackowerflow asking them if they were interested in tutor me a bit extra for some money?

Answer (score 3):

instead of paying to someone you can watch tons of online tutorial that will help you to improve your skills and to do your task, but again you need to have minimum domain knowledge of what you are exactly want to do and how to solve that issues.

Answer (score 1):

I have access to an amazing number of people just like you describe, except for one point - they're absolutely free.

Oh, and a second point - I can get them all in one place.  No need for messing around with Skype or Email.  Where is that place?  Glad you asked:

> http://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what language you want to specialize in, it's hard to provide you with links. Since you tagged PHP, javascript and mysql, I'll focus on those.

My advice would be to start coding in javascript since it has a huge user base, is installed on all browsers, and there are a TON of online tutorials on it. After you get a firm understanding on how to use it, then move to PHP and finally mysql (they both get progressively harder).

If you want super fast responses, then this website is the perfect place. As a rule of thumb, if your question doesn't get answered in the first 15 minutes it will probably never get answered =P that's how quick the responses here are.

Also, godspeed.